# bash - execute multiple processes followed by another

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to do something similar to the following:

```
(task1 & task2) && echo "finished task1 and task2" && task3
```

The goal is that `task1` and `task2` will be executed simultaneously, and once BOTH finished, the latter command will be executed (`echo` and then `task3`)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
task1 &
task2 &
wait         # for both task1 and task2 to finish
echo "finished task1 and task2"
task3
```

Comment: How do I execute that as a single commandline line?

Comment: Use `task1 & task2 & wait; echo XXX; task3`

Comment: Sorry for the hassle. But this will echo, even if task1 or task2 failed..

Comment: Correct. I understood from your question that they must both finish, not that they must be successful.